# Is there a way to modify the .adt file directly?

Tags: compiler-construction, ada, gnat

Good day everyone,

I am currently experimenting with the ASIS tool for ADA programs. I was wondering if it was possible to directly modify the abstract syntax tree (.adt) generated during compilation. If so, can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that messing with abstract syntax tree files would be more work than it was worth.

Instead I would seriously consider using something like [gnat2xml](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_ugn_16.html) to generate the equivalent of the adt file as an XML file. Now you have the Ada syntax and semantic information in a form for which there exists a plethora of tools that can mess around with its structure and content. Once you've made whatever changes you want, run it back through [xml2gnat](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_ugn_16.html#SEC228) to generate the altered Ada source code.

Comment: This is good advice. I was less than impressed by the schema they’ve used, though; it seemed rather ad-hoc and inconsistent.